# Recommendation - Zsh vs FishShell. Scripting, productivity and poweruser perse

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, fish

I have spent sometime trying to pick one, on net comparisons are for zsh vs bash and fish vs bash. But, I could not find any comparison for zsh vs fish. I program in C and C++, apart from hello-world types, never done any major scripting. But now trying my hands at python and shell-scripts. Which shell keeps more juice in terms of productivity first and then development?
Or in the end, the power and usability of any shell comes to its _rc files. So am I good enough with bash?

Comment: `fish` for interactive use, `zsh` for scripting -- if it's just between those two. Personally, I think keeping in good habits re: POSIX sh compliance is important enough to stick with bash, or ksh if I care more about performance.

Comment: ...that said, this question is explicitly against the rules here; there's a close reason specifically for recommend-a-tool requests, *and* another one for opinion-focused questions.

Comment: Good comparison of different shells - http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells

Comment: One thing: Trying to grasp the full range of bash functionality is pretty easy. Trying to do the same thing with zsh is nearly impossible. There are so many possibilities. It's like the C++ of shell languages. This can be a good thing or a bad thing. I've used bash for some years, then changed to zsh for a year or so and then changed back, because I felt like trying to understand zsh was coming in the way of my general productivity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Historically there was a flame ware of sorts between the C shells (CSH and TCSH) and Bash. The complaint against the CSH variants are that they're bad for scripting.

In the years I've been a CLI junkie, I've *never* done any standalone scripts where the scripting language was picked because that's what my shell was.

I've written a variety of scripts that can broadly be divided into two categories:

1. Those that help my command line productivity
2. Those that are not directly related to my command line productivity.

Scripts in category 1. are almost always written in my shell scripting language (often as functions as I'm using ZSH and was previously using BASH both of which support functions).

Scripts in category 2. are written in whatever seems like the most efficient (both development time and running time taken into consideration). I often find myself writing small scripts in Perl, C (compiled, obviously), BASH/ZSH/SH or what ever else I want. I've done a little Python scripting (but not much), and even resort to Java on occasion (compiled-ish, again).

So what am I babbling about? Don't base you choice of shell on its standalone scripting capabilities. Choose your shell for it's utility to you as a shell. Script in whatever else you choose. You'll probably be good enough with BASH as your shell (though I like ZSH a bit more,  **/* globbing is nice and a few other small things, but most scripts I've written for ZSH are early identical to their BASH counterparts).

Comment: Re: `**/*` -- modern (4.x) versions of bash also support recursive globs; see `shopt -s globstar`. The thing that's a big difference in my view is string-splitting behavior on unquoted expansions; zsh does it the sane way, whereas bash does it the way that's compatible with POSIX. There's definitely a lot of room for legitimate difference in terms of what one prefers here; personally, I go for compliance with the ill-thought-out but ubiquitous standard.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same question and found :

- page that compare [Unix Shells: Bash, Fish, Ksh, Tcsh, Zsh](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells) ;
- [Bash vs Zsh (vs Fish)](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1csl7c/bash_vs_zsh/) a reddit thread ;
- [What are the best Unix shells?](http://www.slant.co/topics/151/compare/~zsh_vs_fish_vs_bash)

Answer (score 5):

if you can't find any comparison between zsh vs fish, then try them out yourself. That's the only way you can tell which one you prefer, nobody else can tell you that. Also, define the meaning of productivity. For me, its the abundance of modules and the language's internal capabilities. If you have started with Python, go for it. As for shells, you can learn less of it (not saying totally forget about it), with regards to maybe understanding your rc scripts and other system stuffs etc. Beyond that, Python can do what the shell does.

Answer (score 3):

You'll be most productive in an environment you already know. I used bash for years and its fine. It [completes almost everything](http://www.caliban.org/bash/), can be [used with git](http://blog.bitfluent.com/post/27983389/git-utilities-you-cant-live-without), [mercurial](http://stevelosh.com/blog/entry/2009/3/17/mercurial-bash-prompts/) ...

Comment: *every* shell can be used with GIT, Mercurial, etc :-)